# Filling in the enclosed space of an SVG?

Tags: svg

So I converted a PNG sketch of a fashion model to an SVG because it made the lines look a lot cleaner and more defined. The end goal is to have the user click on a color and it fills in the the separate articles of clothing with the selected color. My only problem is I can't really figure out how (or if there is way) to simply fill in the space enclosed by an SVG.

I'm also not sure if the complexity of the SVG is a problem. Because it's a sketch it's composed of many short lines that the SVG format has made into seemingly one smooth line.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="370.000000pt" height="1000.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 370.000000 1000.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,1000.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M1885 9350 c-72 -9 -111 -18 -179 -43 -108 -40 -206 -235 -206 -411
0 -76 -2 -84 -26 -107 -24 -22 -26 -29 -21 -79 3 -31 17 -80 32 -110 34 -71
37 -83 36 -155 -1 -47 -7 -68 -27 -97 -17 -25 -24 -43 -19 -57 5 -16 2 -21
-13 -21 -27 0 -38 -17 -46 -68 -8 -51 -50 -99 -117 -132 -24 -12 -58 -33 -76
-46 -17 -13 -36 -24 -40 -24 -15 0 -80 -73 -98 -110 -29 -57 -62 -90 -184
-186 -76 -59 -132 -111 -161 -152 -169 -231 -190 -263 -190 -290 0 -16 -6 -50
-14 -76 -10 -33 -13 -79 -9 -164 5 -119 1 -149 -36 -254 -18 -53 -20 -82 -19
-339 0 -194 -3 -284 -11 -292 -6 -6 -11 -22 -11 -35 0 -13 -5 -32 -10 -42 -6
-10 -13 -70 -16 -132 l-6 -113 60 -120 c59 -116 130 -221 175 -258 12 -9 51
-32 86 -50 54 -27 71 -43 119 -112 30 -44 71 -96 90 -115 19 -19 42 -51 53
-71 10 -20 29 -49 42 -65 46 -55 49 -69 28 -111 -10 -21 -27 -86 -36 -145 -16
-101 -16 -119 0 -300 19 -215 19 -230 5 -517 -7 -129 -15 -215 -24 -235 -31
-72 -45 -125 -50 -201 -3 -44 -8 -112 -12 -152 -4 -44 -2 -83 5 -104 11 -32 0
-100 -21 -124 -17 -19 -8 -76 18 -115 20 -29 24 -43 16 -53 -13 -16 -38 -90
-47 -140 -4 -28 -2 -46 10 -64 15 -23 15 -26 -1 -38 -17 -12 -17 -19 -7 -67 7
-36 8 -85 2 -153 -5 -55 -7 -118 -4 -140 28 -253 39 -310 62 -333 13 -13 23
-33 23 -45 0 -13 16 -101 36 -197 19 -96 36 -184 36 -195 0 -11 9 -72 20 -135
23 -132 21 -230 -5 -258 -24 -26 -21 -41 8 -52 20 -8 25 -16 23 -37 -3 -24 1
-28 24 -31 26 -3 28 -6 28 -52 0 -57 -7 -80 -25 -80 -8 0 -16 -17 -20 -41 -7
-42 -26 -100 -69 -208 -52 -131 -44 -226 22 -260 20 -11 48 -30 62 -43 27 -26
68 -51 120 -74 19 -9 55 -28 80 -44 25 -15 88 -43 140 -62 l95 -33 215 0 c190
0 219 2 243 18 22 14 27 25 27 57 0 53 -11 78 -59 130 -22 25 -41 48 -41 52 0
3 -38 50 -85 104 -47 54 -85 102 -85 106 0 13 46 9 143 -13 50 -12 124 -27
162 -34 69 -12 253 -85 265 -105 13 -22 156 -41 315 -43 183 -2 244 12 271 64
27 53 19 88 -32 136 -26 24 -51 43 -56 43 -5 0 -25 12 -45 28 -20 15 -66 43
-102 63 -52 28 -71 45 -89 80 -33 62 -49 77 -117 111 -68 33 -115 74 -115 99
0 22 -65 79 -89 79 -37 0 -44 25 -37 118 13 149 15 160 29 189 16 33 31 99 53
238 8 55 24 140 34 189 11 49 27 141 36 205 9 63 20 124 25 133 5 10 14 96 20
190 6 103 16 189 25 212 11 28 12 42 4 51 -8 10 -7 16 2 24 65 52 98 87 103
110 3 16 17 43 30 61 13 18 21 38 17 44 -10 16 -3 122 13 196 8 36 26 128 41
205 15 77 40 181 56 230 44 138 50 184 37 323 -9 93 -9 144 0 215 7 50 16 207
21 347 11 288 14 310 42 310 11 0 33 14 50 31 30 29 31 32 25 99 -3 37 -11 86
-18 108 -11 38 -10 43 26 100 40 65 64 124 65 159 0 13 -15 40 -33 60 -23 26
-39 58 -49 103 -21 84 -35 120 -48 120 -5 0 -10 4 -10 9 0 5 -5 22 -11 38 -25
59 -60 158 -60 168 0 6 3 49 8 96 5 47 5 101 0 120 -4 19 -10 124 -14 234 l-5
200 35 32 c49 44 53 76 22 158 -14 37 -25 82 -25 100 0 38 -32 116 -56 136
-14 11 -15 26 -9 92 4 47 3 83 -3 90 -6 7 -15 48 -22 91 -6 44 -15 89 -20 100
-4 12 -13 41 -20 66 -25 90 -80 231 -100 257 -11 14 -20 31 -20 38 0 18 -27
38 -110 81 -103 53 -103 53 -69 92 16 18 29 41 29 52 0 32 -19 70 -37 77 -35
12 -53 46 -53 101 0 59 -20 115 -45 129 -15 9 -9 24 53 134 39 69 83 160 97
204 l27 79 -20 17 c-20 15 -20 22 -12 112 5 53 7 103 4 110 -3 9 9 21 33 32
39 19 135 96 185 150 67 73 15 150 -132 195 -25 7 -49 17 -54 22 -6 4 -15 8
-22 8 -6 0 -31 19 -55 43 -63 60 -106 96 -142 117 -58 33 -240 53 -362 40z
m276 -51 c38 -11 82 -31 98 -42 97 -73 120 -91 118 -93 -1 -1 -22 2 -47 6 -25
5 -97 9 -160 9 -135 0 -248 -25 -350 -80 -87 -46 -240 -188 -261 -241 -23 -59
-30 -27 -18 79 7 59 19 108 38 148 16 33 34 75 41 92 13 34 90 93 120 93 10 0
35 7 56 17 34 14 137 27 257 31 22 1 70 -7 108 -19z m214 -180 c38 -11 100
-30 137 -41 74 -22 137 -63 138 -89 0 -25 -103 -123 -182 -174 l-37 -23 -6 40
c-9 54 -66 161 -102 192 -54 49 -99 58 -240 53 -118 -4 -135 -7 -213 -39 -47
-19 -110 -47 -140 -62 -69 -35 -49 -15 56 56 66 45 97 59 170 76 121 29 125
29 244 31 80 1 121 -4 175 -20z m-108 -109 c59 -34 97 -95 109 -177 3 -26 11
-56 15 -65 13 -24 -1 -208 -15 -208 -13 0 -124 56 -144 73 -16 13 -333 11
-433 -3 -37 -5 -107 -23 -157 -40 -49 -16 -93 -30 -97 -30 -3 0 -17 25 -31 55
-41 94 -27 183 25 156 32 -18 41 -13 41 21 0 36 55 93 124 128 37 19 218 99
256 113 8 3 69 6 135 6 115 1 122 0 172 -29z m31 -457 c61 -31 112 -61 112
-67 -1 -31 -79 -212 -110 -251 -4 -5 -23 -40 -43 -76 l-35 -67 28 -27 c24 -23
29 -37 35 -103 7 -74 9 -79 51 -119 44 -43 56 -76 30 -86 -8 -3 -25 -28 -38
-56 l-24 -49 42 -7 c24 -3 58 -16 76 -28 18 -13 52 -33 75 -46 34 -20 47 -36
76 -100 19 -42 39 -89 45 -106 56 -157 101 -382 95 -475 -4 -59 -2 -68 21 -95
27 -31 51 -98 43 -120 -3 -6 6 -38 19 -71 28 -68 31 -122 9 -131 -9 -3 -25
-23 -35 -43 -17 -33 -20 -61 -20 -212 -1 -95 4 -198 11 -228 13 -62 13 -83 -1
-194 -8 -65 -7 -82 5 -100 9 -11 20 -39 26 -61 6 -22 33 -90 60 -151 27 -61
49 -121 49 -134 0 -14 15 -40 36 -61 35 -36 36 -38 24 -76 -7 -21 -21 -50 -32
-65 -10 -15 -30 -52 -44 -82 -21 -46 -33 -59 -82 -86 -31 -18 -75 -47 -97 -65
-22 -17 -67 -49 -100 -71 -55 -36 -65 -39 -130 -39 -38 0 -108 10 -155 21 -47
12 -116 29 -155 38 -38 10 -117 33 -175 51 -60 19 -109 30 -114 25 -5 -5 -19
-5 -32 1 -49 18 -151 37 -202 38 -29 0 -61 3 -71 6 -20 6 -33 46 -20 66 4 8
-7 30 -31 58 -57 69 -83 127 -77 173 7 50 -15 142 -53 223 -16 35 -30 70 -30
77 -1 7 -14 29 -30 48 -22 25 -30 45 -30 72 0 23 -9 53 -24 76 -21 33 -23 46
-18 113 3 61 1 81 -13 102 -15 23 -15 33 -4 84 7 32 16 63 21 70 5 6 13 87 18
180 7 154 23 243 42 243 5 0 8 7 8 15 0 9 9 33 20 55 25 49 25 81 0 153 -12
35 -22 92 -24 149 -6 134 -72 378 -102 378 -24 0 -23 -17 10 -131 19 -63 37
-143 40 -179 12 -118 24 -194 40 -251 l16 -55 -44 -85 -44 -85 -6 -165 c-4
-90 -11 -173 -16 -184 -4 -11 -13 -60 -19 -109 -9 -76 -8 -92 4 -106 18 -20
20 -45 11 -141 -7 -74 -7 -75 18 -87 25 -11 32 -30 27 -76 -1 -11 10 -31 23
-45 26 -28 100 -210 112 -274 4 -23 2 -42 -6 -52 -17 -21 23 -124 77 -196 40
-53 44 -63 45 -122 2 -69 -8 -91 -45 -103 -12 -3 -46 -24 -75 -46 -47 -37 -52
-44 -52 -79 0 -22 -4 -39 -9 -39 -13 0 -153 155 -172 192 -10 18 -27 52 -38
76 -11 23 -31 53 -43 66 -13 13 -24 30 -26 37 -2 8 -12 23 -22 34 -10 11 -25
35 -34 53 -9 17 -20 32 -25 32 -4 0 -43 47 -86 105 -70 95 -84 109 -139 135
-75 35 -120 76 -151 139 -14 27 -32 54 -40 61 -8 7 -15 20 -15 30 0 10 -7 23
-15 30 -8 6 -25 36 -38 64 -22 47 -24 63 -20 152 3 56 14 129 25 169 18 62 21
102 23 350 2 231 5 290 19 335 34 110 36 127 35 255 -2 161 17 250 67 315 18
25 56 79 84 121 58 89 118 147 218 214 40 26 78 57 83 67 5 10 15 18 22 18 14
0 31 24 63 91 24 49 95 116 154 146 40 21 88 54 147 101 34 28 42 41 47 82 6
41 11 49 37 60 26 11 30 17 25 40 -3 19 1 34 14 47 14 15 20 43 25 111 l7 90
37 10 c20 5 72 20 116 32 57 16 121 24 225 29 259 12 233 15 358 -46z m579
-3590 c-4 -3 -3 -11 2 -17 13 -17 22 -119 11 -136 -5 -8 -29 -20 -52 -25 -51
-13 -45 14 -53 -265 -3 -113 -13 -279 -22 -369 -14 -140 -14 -184 -4 -300 l12
-136 -39 -120 c-22 -66 -52 -190 -66 -275 -15 -85 -31 -163 -36 -172 -14 -26
-31 -185 -24 -223 5 -27 2 -35 -15 -44 -12 -7 -21 -17 -21 -23 0 -24 -42 -98
-56 -98 -8 0 -24 -10 -35 -21 -16 -16 -20 -29 -16 -54 4 -25 1 -38 -15 -52
-16 -14 -19 -26 -14 -54 8 -50 -11 -329 -24 -344 -5 -6 -17 -61 -26 -121 -9
-60 -31 -190 -49 -289 -19 -99 -39 -214 -46 -255 -14 -92 -31 -128 -65 -136
-26 -7 -291 0 -299 7 -2 2 0 42 5 89 5 47 14 192 21 322 10 191 10 250 0 305
-17 90 -12 496 7 515 18 18 15 33 -12 65 -19 23 -24 44 -30 125 -7 91 -6 99
14 120 26 29 23 62 -7 66 -30 4 -29 8 8 50 34 38 33 28 6 189 -9 58 -27 109
-57 169 l-43 86 27 86 c23 75 25 88 12 100 -39 40 -76 -37 -139 -289 -14 -53
-29 -105 -35 -116 -23 -41 -34 -193 -21 -274 12 -75 11 -88 -13 -120 -9 -13
-8 -20 5 -33 8 -9 20 -16 26 -16 19 0 12 -16 -11 -28 -13 -6 -40 -17 -62 -24
-45 -15 -60 -44 -53 -100 6 -42 -20 -86 -94 -163 l-38 -40 -4 -245 c-2 -135
-10 -321 -17 -413 -10 -124 -10 -173 -2 -190 6 -12 14 -89 16 -172 7 -197 9
-209 24 -228 8 -9 12 -33 10 -58 -4 -50 -1 -49 -168 -79 -132 -25 -130 -25
-130 5 0 14 -7 28 -15 31 -8 4 -13 9 -11 13 2 3 9 41 15 83 8 60 8 86 -3 124
-8 27 -17 83 -20 124 -4 41 -13 100 -20 130 -8 30 -19 80 -25 110 -5 30 -15
82 -22 115 -6 33 -14 79 -19 103 -4 24 -17 56 -29 72 -28 38 -41 150 -50 425
-6 168 -5 212 6 221 17 15 17 65 -2 91 -13 19 -13 25 0 57 8 19 15 46 15 59 0
13 7 32 15 43 23 30 19 69 -10 88 -24 16 -36 66 -16 66 5 0 14 29 21 64 9 50
9 73 0 101 -9 28 -9 59 -1 130 6 51 11 116 11 143 0 53 12 100 38 147 11 20
19 70 24 150 4 66 12 185 18 265 8 114 7 173 -5 275 -31 285 -30 318 14 483
14 50 24 53 41 13 6 -17 52 -72 101 -123 49 -51 89 -96 89 -100 0 -5 8 -8 18
-8 20 0 135 107 136 126 1 6 16 25 35 43 26 24 32 36 27 55 -3 14 -2 28 4 31
5 3 10 17 10 31 0 13 3 24 6 24 3 0 50 -9 104 -20 54 -11 125 -24 157 -29 32
-5 101 -21 153 -35 52 -15 120 -31 150 -37 30 -6 64 -15 75 -20 11 -5 58 -20
105 -35 112 -35 213 -31 277 9 24 15 45 27 47 27 3 0 36 23 73 51 37 28 84 59
103 68 19 9 39 22 43 29 4 6 13 12 19 12 6 0 8 -3 5 -7z m-1405 -150 c-11 -16
-34 -41 -51 -57 -29 -28 -31 -28 -31 -8 0 13 17 34 46 57 56 42 61 43 36 8z
m349 -1340 c37 -61 49 -92 74 -193 13 -52 26 -102 30 -112 4 -11 -6 -30 -29
-56 -40 -44 -43 -57 -19 -84 14 -15 14 -22 4 -42 -9 -15 -11 -41 -7 -72 3 -27
6 -79 5 -116 0 -65 1 -68 26 -78 24 -9 25 -12 14 -27 -19 -23 -27 -555 -8
-589 9 -17 10 -63 4 -181 -4 -87 -7 -170 -6 -186 1 -15 -3 -56 -9 -90 -6 -34
-15 -125 -20 -202 -12 -164 -36 -274 -69 -308 -15 -17 -29 -54 -41 -112 -11
-47 -31 -108 -46 -135 l-26 -48 -73 76 c-69 72 -73 78 -78 132 -4 31 -13 70
-22 86 -8 16 -15 50 -15 76 0 26 -7 73 -16 105 -9 35 -17 117 -20 208 -2 83
-9 167 -16 188 -9 28 -8 59 1 130 7 50 15 214 17 362 3 149 7 279 9 291 3 12
34 54 71 95 64 72 65 74 59 116 -9 65 -1 79 58 99 29 9 58 21 65 27 18 14 15
51 -7 71 -16 14 -17 22 -8 46 8 22 8 45 -1 88 -7 32 -9 81 -6 108 7 63 44 234
54 255 5 9 11 37 15 63 4 25 9 46 10 46 2 0 13 -17 26 -37z m411 -2182 c-3
-120 6 -147 55 -167 48 -20 73 -42 73 -65 0 -20 78 -88 136 -117 23 -12 53
-35 65 -52 59 -77 91 -108 136 -130 26 -13 71 -41 100 -62 29 -21 55 -38 60
-38 4 0 22 -14 40 -32 66 -64 37 -111 -79 -129 -77 -13 -57 -13 -218 0 -145
11 -170 19 -370 108 -30 14 -77 28 -105 33 -27 5 -70 14 -95 20 -25 7 -92 19
-149 27 -97 14 -106 18 -140 52 l-37 37 28 44 c34 53 65 134 79 204 14 71 29
106 45 106 16 0 17 6 45 151 l22 116 156 -4 156 -4 -3 -98z m-733 -205 c6 -25
11 -59 11 -76 0 -27 13 -44 75 -104 63 -60 75 -77 75 -104 0 -26 11 -44 55
-87 30 -31 55 -60 55 -65 0 -17 67 -114 100 -145 18 -16 57 -62 86 -102 30
-39 58 -75 64 -78 12 -7 13 -55 2 -72 -16 -26 -69 -33 -234 -33 -169 0 -171 0
-277 36 -58 19 -122 45 -141 58 -19 12 -51 28 -70 36 -42 16 -140 79 -140 89
0 4 -12 14 -27 22 -42 21 -49 31 -56 76 -8 49 25 169 74 265 5 9 12 36 15 58
4 23 17 57 30 76 18 26 24 49 24 87 l0 53 88 17 c48 10 94 22 102 27 8 6 29
10 46 10 29 0 33 -4 43 -44z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

If I change the "fill" attribute, I only change the color of the outline. I also can't change the color of the background because the area I want to fill is a more complex shape. Blow is the PNG of the image that I converted to SVG so you get an idea of the shape.

[Imgur link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EquxZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ccprog explained you have a hollow path already filled with black. This is how to solve the problem:

1. I've changed the d attribute of the path to all-absolute. Ypu can do it using this pen by Lea Verou: [Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv)
2. Split the d attribute of the path by the "M" command and create other paths using the fragments as the d attribute.
3. Fill the resulting paths with loud colors so that you can identify the path.
4. Next you can fill them with the colors you like.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="200" viewBox="0 0 370.000000 1000.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

<g transform="translate(0.000000,1000.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
<path id="outline" d="M1885,9350C1813,9341,1774,9332,1706,9307C1598,9267,1500,9072,1500,8896C1500,8820,1498,8812,1474,8789C1450,8767,1448,8760,1453,8710C1456,8679,1470,8630,1485,8600C1519,8529,1522,8517,1521,8445C1520,8398,1514,8377,1494,8348C1477,8323,1470,8305,1475,8291C1480,8275,1477,8270,1462,8270C1435,8270,1424,8253,1416,8202C1408,8151,1366,8103,1299,8070C1275,8058,1241,8037,1223,8024C1206,8011,1187,8000,1183,8000C1168,8000,1103,7927,1085,7890C1056,7833,1023,7800,901,7704C825,7645,769,7593,740,7552C571,7321,550,7289,550,7262C550,7246,544,7212,536,7186C526,7153,523,7107,527,7022C532,6903,528,6873,491,6768C473,6715,471,6686,472,6429C472,6235,469,6145,461,6137C455,6131,450,6115,450,6102C450,6089,445,6070,440,6060C434,6050,427,5990,424,5928L418,5815L478,5695C537,5579,608,5474,653,5437C665,5428,704,5405,739,5387C793,5360,810,5344,858,5275C888,5231,929,5179,948,5160C967,5141,990,5109,1001,5089C1011,5069,1030,5040,1043,5024C1089,4969,1092,4955,1071,4913C1061,4892,1044,4827,1035,4768C1019,4667,1019,4649,1035,4468C1054,4253,1054,4238,1040,3951C1033,3822,1025,3736,1016,3716C985,3644,971,3591,966,3515C963,3471,958,3403,954,3363C950,3319,952,3280,959,3259C970,3227,959,3159,938,3135C921,3116,930,3059,956,3020C976,2991,980,2977,972,2967C959,2951,934,2877,925,2827C921,2799,923,2781,935,2763C950,2740,950,2737,934,2725C917,2713,917,2706,927,2658C934,2622,935,2573,929,2505C924,2450,922,2387,925,2365C953,2112,964,2055,987,2032C1000,2019,1010,1999,1010,1987C1010,1974,1026,1886,1046,1790C1065,1694,1082,1606,1082,1595C1082,1584,1091,1523,1102,1460C1125,1328,1123,1230,1097,1202C1073,1176,1076,1161,1105,1150C1125,1142,1130,1134,1128,1113C1125,1089,1129,1085,1152,1082C1178,1079,1180,1076,1180,1030C1180,973,1173,950,1155,950C1147,950,1139,933,1135,909C1128,867,1109,809,1066,701C1014,570,1022,475,1088,441C1108,430,1136,411,1150,398C1177,372,1218,347,1270,324C1289,315,1325,296,1350,280C1375,265,1438,237,1490,218L1585,185L1800,185C1990,185,2019,187,2043,203C2065,217,2070,228,2070,260C2070,313,2059,338,2011,390C1989,415,1970,438,1970,442C1970,445,1932,492,1885,546C1838,600,1800,648,1800,652C1800,665,1846,661,1943,639C1993,627,2067,612,2105,605C2174,593,2358,520,2370,500C2383,478,2526,459,2685,457C2868,455,2929,469,2956,521C2983,574,2975,609,2924,657C2898,681,2873,700,2868,700C2863,700,2843,712,2823,728C2803,743,2757,771,2721,791C2669,819,2650,836,2632,871C2599,933,2583,948,2515,982C2447,1015,2400,1056,2400,1081C2400,1103,2335,1160,2311,1160C2274,1160,2267,1185,2274,1278C2287,1427,2289,1438,2303,1467C2319,1500,2334,1566,2356,1705C2364,1760,2380,1845,2390,1894C2401,1943,2417,2035,2426,2099C2435,2162,2446,2223,2451,2232C2456,2242,2465,2328,2471,2422C2477,2525,2487,2611,2496,2634C2507,2662,2508,2676,2500,2685C2492,2695,2493,2701,2502,2709C2567,2761,2600,2796,2605,2819C2608,2835,2622,2862,2635,2880C2648,2898,2656,2918,2652,2924C2642,2940,2649,3046,2665,3120C2673,3156,2691,3248,2706,3325C2721,3402,2746,3506,2762,3555C2806,3693,2812,3739,2799,3878C2790,3971,2790,4022,2799,4093C2806,4143,2815,4300,2820,4440C2831,4728,2834,4750,2862,4750C2873,4750,2895,4764,2912,4781C2942,4810,2943,4813,2937,4880C2934,4917,2926,4966,2919,4988C2908,5026,2909,5031,2945,5088C2985,5153,3009,5212,3010,5247C3010,5260,2995,5287,2977,5307C2954,5333,2938,5365,2928,5410C2907,5494,2893,5530,2880,5530C2875,5530,2870,5534,2870,5539C2870,5544,2865,5561,2859,5577C2834,5636,2799,5735,2799,5745C2799,5751,2802,5794,2807,5841C2812,5888,2812,5942,2807,5961C2803,5980,2797,6085,2793,6195L2788,6395L2823,6427C2872,6471,2876,6503,2845,6585C2831,6622,2820,6667,2820,6685C2820,6723,2788,6801,2764,6821C2750,6832,2749,6847,2755,6913C2759,6960,2758,6996,2752,7003C2746,7010,2737,7051,2730,7094C2724,7138,2715,7183,2710,7194C2706,7206,2697,7235,2690,7260C2665,7350,2610,7491,2590,7517C2579,7531,2570,7548,2570,7555C2570,7573,2543,7593,2460,7636C2357,7689,2357,7689,2391,7728C2407,7746,2420,7769,2420,7780C2420,7812,2401,7850,2383,7857C2348,7869,2330,7903,2330,7958C2330,8017,2310,8073,2285,8087C2270,8096,2276,8111,2338,8221C2377,8290,2421,8381,2435,8425L2462,8504L2442,8521C2422,8536,2422,8543,2430,8633C2435,8686,2437,8736,2434,8743C2431,8752,2443,8764,2467,8775C2506,8794,2602,8871,2652,8925C2719,8998,2667,9075,2520,9120C2495,9127,2471,9137,2466,9142C2460,9146,2451,9150,2444,9150C2438,9150,2413,9169,2389,9193C2326,9253,2283,9289,2247,9310C2189,9343,2007,9363,1885,9350Z" fill="black"/>
<path id="cap" d="         M2161,9299C2199,9288,2243,9268,2259,9257C2356,9184,2379,9166,2377,9164C2376,9163,2355,9166,2330,9170C2305,9175,2233,9179,2170,9179C2035,9179,1922,9154,1820,9099C1733,9053,1580,8911,1559,8858C1536,8799,1529,8831,1541,8937C1548,8996,1560,9045,1579,9085C1595,9118,1613,9160,1620,9177C1633,9211,1710,9270,1740,9270C1750,9270,1775,9277,1796,9287C1830,9301,1933,9314,2053,9318C2075,9319,2123,9311,2161,9299Z" fill="red"/>
<path id="peak" d="         M2375,9119C2413,9108,2475,9089,2512,9078C2586,9056,2649,9015,2650,8989C2650,8964,2547,8866,2468,8815L2431,8792L2425,8832C2416,8886,2359,8993,2323,9024C2269,9073,2224,9082,2083,9077C1965,9073,1948,9070,1870,9038C1823,9019,1760,8991,1730,8976C1661,8941,1681,8961,1786,9032C1852,9077,1883,9091,1956,9108C2077,9137,2081,9137,2200,9139C2280,9140,2321,9135,2375,9119Z" fill="pink" />
<path id="eyes" d="M2267,9010C2326,8976,2364,8915,2376,8833C2379,8807,2387,8777,2391,8768C2404,8744,2390,8560,2376,8560C2363,8560,2252,8616,2232,8633C2216,8646,1899,8644,1799,8630C1762,8625,1692,8607,1642,8590C1593,8574,1549,8560,1545,8560C1542,8560,1528,8585,1514,8615C1473,8709,1487,8798,1539,8771C1571,8753,1580,8758,1580,8792C1580,8828,1635,8885,1704,8920C1741,8939,1922,9019,1960,9033C1968,9036,2029,9039,2095,9039C2210,9040,2217,9039,2267,9010Z" fill="purple" />
<path id="blouse" d="M2298,8553C2359,8522,2410,8492,2410,8486C2409,8455,2331,8274,2300,8235C2296,8230,2277,8195,2257,8159L2222,8092L2250,8065C2274,8042,2279,8028,2285,7962C2292,7888,2294,7883,2336,7843C2380,7800,2392,7767,2366,7757C2358,7754,2341,7729,2328,7701L2304,7652L2346,7645C2370,7642,2404,7629,2422,7617C2440,7604,2474,7584,2497,7571C2531,7551,2544,7535,2573,7471C2592,7429,2612,7382,2618,7365C2674,7208,2719,6983,2713,6890C2709,6831,2711,6822,2734,6795C2761,6764,2785,6697,2777,6675C2774,6669,2783,6637,2796,6604C2824,6536,2827,6482,2805,6473C2796,6470,2780,6450,2770,6430C2753,6397,2750,6369,2750,6218C2749,6123,2754,6020,2761,5990C2774,5928,2774,5907,2760,5796C2752,5731,2753,5714,2765,5696C2774,5685,2785,5657,2791,5635C2797,5613,2824,5545,2851,5484C2878,5423,2900,5363,2900,5350C2900,5336,2915,5310,2936,5289C2971,5253,2972,5251,2960,5213C2953,5192,2939,5163,2928,5148C2918,5133,2898,5096,2884,5066C2863,5020,2851,5007,2802,4980C2771,4962,2727,4933,2705,4915C2683,4898,2638,4866,2605,4844C2550,4808,2540,4805,2475,4805C2437,4805,2367,4815,2320,4826C2273,4838,2204,4855,2165,4864C2127,4874,2048,4897,1990,4915C1930,4934,1881,4945,1876,4940C1871,4935,1857,4935,1844,4941C1795,4959,1693,4978,1642,4979C1613,4979,1581,4982,1571,4985C1551,4991,1538,5031,1551,5051C1555,5059,1544,5081,1520,5109C1463,5178,1437,5236,1443,5282C1450,5332,1428,5424,1390,5505C1374,5540,1360,5575,1360,5582C1359,5589,1346,5611,1330,5630C1308,5655,1300,5675,1300,5702C1300,5725,1291,5755,1276,5778C1255,5811,1253,5824,1258,5891C1261,5952,1259,5972,1245,5993C1230,6016,1230,6026,1241,6077C1248,6109,1257,6140,1262,6147C1267,6153,1275,6234,1280,6327C1287,6481,1303,6570,1322,6570C1327,6570,1330,6577,1330,6585C1330,6594,1339,6618,1350,6640C1375,6689,1375,6721,1350,6793C1338,6828,1328,6885,1326,6942C1320,7076,1254,7320,1224,7320C1200,7320,1201,7303,1234,7189C1253,7126,1271,7046,1274,7010C1286,6892,1298,6816,1314,6759L1330,6704L1286,6619L1242,6534L1236,6369C1232,6279,1225,6196,1220,6185C1216,6174,1207,6125,1201,6076C1192,6000,1193,5984,1205,5970C1223,5950,1225,5925,1216,5829C1209,5755,1209,5754,1234,5742C1259,5731,1266,5712,1261,5666C1260,5655,1271,5635,1284,5621C1310,5593,1384,5411,1396,5347C1400,5324,1398,5305,1390,5295C1373,5274,1413,5171,1467,5099C1507,5046,1511,5036,1512,4977C1514,4908,1504,4886,1467,4874C1455,4871,1421,4850,1392,4828C1345,4791,1340,4784,1340,4749C1340,4727,1336,4710,1331,4710C1318,4710,1178,4865,1159,4902C1149,4920,1132,4954,1121,4978C1110,5001,1090,5031,1078,5044C1065,5057,1054,5074,1052,5081C1050,5089,1040,5104,1030,5115C1020,5126,1005,5150,996,5168C987,5185,976,5200,971,5200C967,5200,928,5247,885,5305C815,5400,801,5414,746,5440C671,5475,626,5516,595,5579C581,5606,563,5633,555,5640C547,5647,540,5660,540,5670C540,5680,533,5693,525,5700C517,5706,500,5736,487,5764C465,5811,463,5827,467,5916C470,5972,481,6045,492,6085C510,6147,513,6187,515,6435C517,6666,520,6725,534,6770C568,6880,570,6897,569,7025C567,7186,586,7275,636,7340C654,7365,692,7419,720,7461C778,7550,838,7608,938,7675C978,7701,1016,7732,1021,7742C1026,7752,1036,7760,1043,7760C1057,7760,1074,7784,1106,7851C1130,7900,1201,7967,1260,7997C1300,8018,1348,8051,1407,8098C1441,8126,1449,8139,1454,8180C1460,8221,1465,8229,1491,8240C1517,8251,1521,8257,1516,8280C1513,8299,1517,8314,1530,8327C1544,8342,1550,8370,1555,8438L1562,8528L1599,8538C1619,8543,1671,8558,1715,8570C1772,8586,1836,8594,1940,8599C2199,8611,2173,8614,2298,8553Z" fill="darkgreen"/>
<path id="pants" d="M2877,4963C2873,4960,2874,4952,2879,4946C2892,4929,2901,4827,2890,4810C2885,4802,2861,4790,2838,4785C2787,4772,2793,4799,2785,4520C2782,4407,2772,4241,2763,4151C2749,4011,2749,3967,2759,3851L2771,3715L2732,3595C2710,3529,2680,3405,2666,3320C2651,3235,2635,3157,2630,3148C2616,3122,2599,2963,2606,2925C2611,2898,2608,2890,2591,2881C2579,2874,2570,2864,2570,2858C2570,2834,2528,2760,2514,2760C2506,2760,2490,2750,2479,2739C2463,2723,2459,2710,2463,2685C2467,2660,2464,2647,2448,2633C2432,2619,2429,2607,2434,2579C2442,2529,2423,2250,2410,2235C2405,2229,2393,2174,2384,2114C2375,2054,2353,1924,2335,1825C2316,1726,2296,1611,2289,1570C2275,1478,2258,1442,2224,1434C2198,1427,1933,1434,1925,1441C1923,1443,1925,1483,1930,1530C1935,1577,1944,1722,1951,1852C1961,2043,1961,2102,1951,2157C1934,2247,1939,2653,1958,2672C1976,2690,1973,2705,1946,2737C1927,2760,1922,2781,1916,2862C1909,2953,1910,2961,1930,2982C1956,3011,1953,3044,1923,3048C1893,3052,1894,3056,1931,3098C1965,3136,1964,3126,1937,3287C1928,3345,1910,3396,1880,3456L1837,3542L1864,3628C1887,3703,1889,3716,1876,3728C1837,3768,1800,3691,1737,3439C1723,3386,1708,3334,1702,3323C1679,3282,1668,3130,1681,3049C1693,2974,1692,2961,1668,2929C1659,2916,1660,2909,1673,2896C1681,2887,1693,2880,1699,2880C1718,2880,1711,2864,1688,2852C1675,2846,1648,2835,1626,2828C1581,2813,1566,2784,1573,2728C1579,2686,1553,2642,1479,2565L1441,2525L1437,2280C1435,2145,1427,1959,1420,1867C1410,1743,1410,1694,1418,1677C1424,1665,1432,1588,1434,1505C1441,1308,1443,1296,1458,1277C1466,1268,1470,1244,1468,1219C1464,1169,1467,1170,1300,1140C1168,1115,1170,1115,1170,1145C1170,1159,1163,1173,1155,1176C1147,1180,1142,1185,1144,1189C1146,1192,1153,1230,1159,1272C1167,1332,1167,1358,1156,1396C1148,1423,1139,1479,1136,1520C1132,1561,1123,1620,1116,1650C1108,1680,1097,1730,1091,1760C1086,1790,1076,1842,1069,1875C1063,1908,1055,1954,1050,1978C1046,2002,1033,2034,1021,2050C993,2088,980,2200,971,2475C965,2643,966,2687,977,2696C994,2711,994,2761,975,2787C962,2806,962,2812,975,2844C983,2863,990,2890,990,2903C990,2916,997,2935,1005,2946C1028,2976,1024,3015,995,3034C971,3050,959,3100,979,3100C984,3100,993,3129,1000,3164C1009,3214,1009,3237,1000,3265C991,3293,991,3324,999,3395C1005,3446,1010,3511,1010,3538C1010,3591,1022,3638,1048,3685C1059,3705,1067,3755,1072,3835C1076,3901,1084,4020,1090,4100C1098,4214,1097,4273,1085,4375C1054,4660,1055,4693,1099,4858C1113,4908,1123,4911,1140,4871C1146,4854,1192,4799,1241,4748C1290,4697,1330,4652,1330,4648C1330,4643,1338,4640,1348,4640C1368,4640,1483,4747,1484,4766C1485,4772,1500,4791,1519,4809C1545,4833,1551,4845,1546,4864C1543,4878,1544,4892,1550,4895C1555,4898,1560,4912,1560,4926C1560,4939,1563,4950,1566,4950C1569,4950,1616,4941,1670,4930C1724,4919,1795,4906,1827,4901C1859,4896,1928,4880,1980,4866C2032,4851,2100,4835,2130,4829C2160,4823,2194,4814,2205,4809C2216,4804,2263,4789,2310,4774C2422,4739,2523,4743,2587,4783C2611,4798,2632,4810,2634,4810C2637,4810,2670,4833,2707,4861C2744,4889,2791,4920,2810,4929C2829,4938,2849,4951,2853,4958C2857,4964,2866,4970,2872,4970C2878,4970,2880,4967,2877,4963Z" fill="lightgreen"/>
<path id="sleevetip" d="M1472,4813C1461,4797,1438,4772,1421,4756C1392,4728,1390,4728,1390,4748C1390,4761,1407,4782,1436,4805C1492,4847,1497,4848,1472,4813Z" fill="black"/>
<path id="hole" d="M1821,3473C1858,3412,1870,3381,1895,3280C1908,3228,1921,3178,1925,3168C1929,3157,1919,3138,1896,3112C1856,3068,1853,3055,1877,3028C1891,3013,1891,3006,1881,2986C1872,2971,1870,2945,1874,2914C1877,2887,1880,2835,1879,2798C1879,2733,1880,2730,1905,2720C1929,2711,1930,2708,1919,2693C1900,2670,1892,2138,1911,2104C1920,2087,1921,2041,1915,1923C1911,1836,1908,1753,1909,1737C1910,1722,1906,1681,1900,1647C1894,1613,1885,1522,1880,1445C1868,1281,1844,1171,1811,1137C1796,1120,1782,1083,1770,1025C1759,978,1739,917,1724,890L1698,842L1625,918C1556,990,1552,996,1547,1050C1543,1081,1534,1120,1525,1136C1517,1152,1510,1186,1510,1212C1510,1238,1503,1285,1494,1317C1485,1352,1477,1434,1474,1525C1472,1608,1465,1692,1458,1713C1449,1741,1450,1772,1459,1843C1466,1893,1474,2057,1476,2205C1479,2354,1483,2484,1485,2496C1488,2508,1519,2550,1556,2591C1620,2663,1621,2665,1615,2707C1606,2772,1614,2786,1673,2806C1702,2815,1731,2827,1738,2833C1756,2847,1753,2884,1731,2904C1715,2918,1714,2926,1723,2950C1731,2972,1731,2995,1722,3038C1715,3070,1713,3119,1716,3146C1723,3209,1760,3380,1770,3401C1775,3410,1781,3438,1785,3464C1789,3489,1794,3510,1795,3510C1797,3510,1808,3493,1821,3473Z" fill="white"/>
<path id="rightshoe" d="M2232,1291C2229,1171,2238,1144,2287,1124C2335,1104,2360,1082,2360,1059C2360,1039,2438,971,2496,942C2519,930,2549,907,2561,890C2620,813,2652,782,2697,760C2723,747,2768,719,2797,698C2826,677,2852,660,2857,660C2861,660,2879,646,2897,628C2963,564,2934,517,2818,499C2741,486,2761,486,2600,499C2455,510,2430,518,2230,607C2200,621,2153,635,2125,640C2098,645,2055,654,2030,660C2005,667,1938,679,1881,687C1784,701,1775,705,1741,739L1704,776L1732,820C1766,873,1797,954,1811,1024C1825,1095,1840,1130,1856,1130C1872,1130,1873,1136,1901,1281L1923,1397L2079,1393L2235,1389L2232,1291Z" fill="blue"/>
<path id="leftshoe" d="M1499,1086C1505,1061,1510,1027,1510,1010C1510,983,1523,966,1585,906C1648,846,1660,829,1660,802C1660,776,1671,758,1715,715C1745,684,1770,655,1770,650C1770,633,1837,536,1870,505C1888,489,1927,443,1956,403C1986,364,2014,328,2020,325C2032,318,2033,270,2022,253C2006,227,1953,220,1788,220C1619,220,1617,220,1511,256C1453,275,1389,301,1370,314C1351,326,1319,342,1300,350C1258,366,1160,429,1160,439C1160,443,1148,453,1133,461C1091,482,1084,492,1077,537C1069,586,1102,706,1151,802C1156,811,1163,838,1166,860C1170,883,1183,917,1196,936C1214,962,1220,985,1220,1023L1220,1076L1308,1093C1356,1103,1402,1115,1410,1120C1418,1126,1439,1130,1456,1130C1485,1130,1489,1126,1499,1086Z" fill="darkorange"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Interesting and helpful answer for me

Comment: Wow I didn't expect it to work this well! You just did something I spent the past week trying to do nonstop

Answer (score 2):

Your SVG is in a state that can be developed easily into what you need. The following image shows what actually has been outlined:

[image]

As you can see, the path goes around *each side* of the lines. That is why a change of `fill` only changes the black lines: what visually seems to be a line is actually a long and small enclosed area.

You can use that state to your advantage. This is done best with a visual SVG editor of some sort - Inkscape, Sketch or Illustrator for example.

1. Divide up the one path you currently have into its individual, closed parts. Editors have a "Break apart" command for that.
2. The outermost part now encloses the whole figure. Note there should be an "empty" space between the legs. Select the outermost path and the one surrounding that space and combine them back together (actually the reverse action to the previous one).
3. Move this object behind all other paths that are part of the figure and fill it with black.
4. Each other of the remaining paths can now be filled with colors of your liking. since they are sitting in front of the black background part. The only black that remains visible is in the gaps and on the outside - as if it was lines.

Comment: Wow seeing the SVG like that really helped me understand how this sort of file works. Thank you so much!